# Validate uploaded file extension with Symfony?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms

I would like to prevent users from uploading files with certain extensions.
First thing that comes to mind is to use sfValidatorRegex like this:

```
$this->setValidator('name', new sfValidatorRegex(array(
    'pattern' => '/\.htaccess$/i',
    'must_match' => false,
)));
```

But, this doesn't work, because sfValidatorRegex::doClean($value) gets an instance of sfValidatedFile, rathen than filename.

**UPD**: Sorry to have confused you guys, I really want to validate extension, not file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sfValidatorFile` can validate by mime type via the mime_type option. It also has support for mime_type categories, though the only built-in one is for web images. Open `sfValidatorFile` and take a look!

Also note that you should NOT be validating file types via extensions. Extensions are completely arbitrary.

Comment: Why not? For example, I want to prevent user from uploading files with .htaccess extension.

Comment: I could have a PNG with the extension .htaccess or an htaccess file with extension PNG. It's understandable to block the extension .htaccess but is has nothing to do with the file's *type*.

Comment: Your answer could be clearer - mime-type and extension are not the same thing, and symfony knows best in this case. Delete your last sentence :)

Comment: my fault! What I really meant is 'extension' rather than file type.